# Download Debian packages and dependencies on Windows?

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management

I am working in a restricted environment. I have a Debian system (Jessie) with no internet connection. I want to download the packages and dependencies on a Windows machine (where I don't have admin privileges) and then install them on the Debian system (I have root access to the Debian system).

How can I download the packages? Can I download them using a browser?

Is it possible to download the whole repository as ISOs? If so, how big is it? Where can I find this information?

This for a project where I need to develop a driver.

I might need simple things like `gcc` or maybe some utility software. The problem is that the uncertainty is too high as to what I might need during the project. So I need a solution where I can either:

1. download any package anytime I want on a Windows machine and then install it on the Debian system, or
2. just download the complete repository on Windows and set it up as offline repository.

In any case, the download is possible only on a Windows Machine with no Admin privileges.

Comment: Too complicated, too many dependencies. Think about setting up an APT proxy somewhere in your network; the fact a server has the requirement to not have a Internet connection does not mean it cannot be updated with apt.

Comment: What exactly do you want to install? I can't understand if you need any "special" software that you will need after the installation of the Debian. In any case, please check: http://sohcahtoa.org.uk/pages/wheezy-offgrid.html

Comment: Did you have synaptic package manager installed on debian ?

Comment: @GAD3R I will installing Debian OS from the 3 DVDs from http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/ I'm not sure if it has synaptic package manager.

Comment: @blametheadmin I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a second Debian system somewhere that does have internet access, you can use [apt-offline](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) to let it handle the necessary dependencies for you on the restricted machines, and the download all necessary packages onto some medium on the machine with internet access.

I'm not sure how to extract the information about which packages are needed directly on the Windows machine; installing a VM etc. with a minimal Debian system, or using a live CD/USB stick is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: AFAIK apt-offline does not need any Debian machine with internet access. It's for installing packages on a totally offline Debian machine. So it's a perfect fit for the OP's first point, which is probably the better option if that online Windows machine is always easily available. If not, then the full DVD set is a reasonable solution for the second point.

Comment: @FerencWágner I haven't used apt-offline yet, but from the description it looks like you also need to use `apt-offline get` to downloaded the selected files on the online-machine based on the signature generated on the offline-machine. How would you do that in Windows?

Comment: See the discussion at https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT. Basically: "You will need python installed on the windows box. Then just download the apt-offline zip archive from the alioth project page, unzip it and execute it." I could only find a [nighly snapshot](https://alioth.debian.org/snapshots.php?group_id=100399), though. "Its not necessary for Python to be *installed*... You can put Python on the same stick you plan to download to, and just add `X:\<Python Directory>\bin` to `PATH` and continue as normal."

Answer (score 2):

1) Look at something like "Sushi Huh?"

> But "Sushi, huh?" can also run on both Linux and Windows, meaning you can download the packages with dependencies from Windows too.

Old link but still alive: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/sushi-huh-easily-download-packages-for.html

"Sushi Huh?" is still going: http://sushi-huh.sourceforge.net/

2) There is also the "Keryx Project".

It's mostly for Ubuntu, but it is said to work for other distros.

> If you have an Ubuntu machine without an internet connection,you can try Keryx to download all updates on another Windows/Linux PC and keep the Ubuntu machine updating off-line via an USB. - http://ubuntuguide.net/update-ubuntu-off-line-via-another-windowslinux-pc-using-keryx

And https://launchpad.net/keryx