# Raspbian/Debian - Install .deb offline

Tags: debian, raspbian, dkms

I need to install a `.deb` package on a raspberryPi that doesn't have connectivity. When I try to install such package using:

```
sudo dpkg -i <name>.deb
```

I get the error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rtl8192eu-dkms:
  rtl8192eu-dkms depends on dkms (>= 1.95); however:
     package dkms is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8192eu-dkms (--install)
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
errors were encountered while processing:
  rtl8192eu-dkms
```

I do have another windows machine that I could download files from, but where do I get those files?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341951/download-debian-packages-and-dependancies-on-windows/341957#341957) (`apt-offline` or `Sushi Huh?` are much more convenient than tracking dependencies manually).

Comment: @dirkt, apparently i dont have another linux machine (as i have windows) so yeah...

Comment: Sushi Huh? works on Windows too. http://sushi-huh.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Both `apt-offline` and `Sushi Huh` allow you to download the packages on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must install `dkms` and all its dependencies at the same time or before installing rtl8192eu-dkms. For example: `dpkg -i rtl8192eu-dkms.deb dkms.deb` or `dpkg -i dkms.deb && dpkg -i rtl8192eu-dkms.deb`.

Comment: well i think that's quite obvious, but where do I get the actual .deb files for dkms

Comment: @Deimantux http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.3-2_all.deb

Comment: Well thanks for that there, I'll let you know of further issues. I'll mark as correct once the timer runs out

Answer (score 2):

A .deb package has dependencies like a .rpm.

To check depends of package

```
dpkg -I namepackage.deb|grep Dep
```