# Raspbian/Debian Jessie: Upgrading the kernel offline

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I got raspbian (debian jessie) installed on my raspberry pi that currently has no internet. I also have a windows machine with full internet access.

The package that I'm installing says that

```
Module build for kernel 4.4.34+ was skipped since the kernel
headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed
```

Furthermore, uname -r states:

```
4.4.34+
```

How would i go about upgrading those kernel headers
Edit: I don't have another unix system and I don't want to use a VM

Comment: Answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341951/download-debian-packages-and-dependancies-on-windows/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download Debian packages and dependancies on windows?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341951/download-debian-packages-and-dependancies-on-windows)

Comment: @dirkt nope, none of those answer the question, _you're just promoting **your own answer** that doesnt help me in any shape way or form_

Comment: How does it not help you? You need the `linux-headers-*` Debian package for your kernel (I thought that was the obvious part). As you don't have Internet on your Pi (that's the difficult part), download using `apt-offline` or `Sushi Huh?`, as described in the answer. And I used the question with my own answer because that was quickest to find, not to "promote" my answer - I think there's at least another duplicate at superuser, and possibly more here.

Comment: @dirkt, no stop promoting your answers at the expense of other people's time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apt-get --print-uris`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) to install your package. A detailed tuto can be found on [Ubuntu-help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/PrintUris)

```
--print-uris

Instead of fetching the files to install, their URIs are printed. Each 
URI will have the path, the destination file name, the size and the 
expected  md5 hash. Note that the file name to write to will not always 
match the file  name on the remote site! This also works with the source 
and update commands.  When used with the update command, the MD5 and size 
are not included, and it  is up to the user to decompress any compressed 
files.
```

In your case , the needed package is :`linux-headers`

```
 sudo apt-get --print-uris --yes install linux-headers-$(uname -r) | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 > packageuri.htm
```

Comment: Seems to be working at the first glance, then gives the error `unable to locate package linux-headers-4.4.34`